# How to setup Service accounts in Dataflow jobs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Need to setup service account in Dataflow program which pull messages from subscribers and do the transformation on data and finally store in BigQuery table.

Approach:

```
GoogleCredential credentials = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("credentials.json")).createScoped(Collections.singleton(??));
```

Couldn't find the correct scope. Appreciate your help with code and invoking Dataflow job using credential setup.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code to trigger dataflow job from Java API to GCP platform.

Scope code:

```
final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub");
```

DataflowpipelineOptions code:

```
options.setGcpCredential(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
                    new FileInputStream("abc.json")).createScoped(SCOPES));
```

Comment: Is it possible to add scopes to default credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you're trying to pull data from, but here's a list of available scopes for Google products https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

Comment: Trying pull messages in dataflow jobs i.e using java code.